# How to Prevent an Invalid Workflow Action from Executing

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, azure-queues

I have an existing Workflow engine that picks up xml messages from an Azure queue. The XML piece has the information on the WorkflowAction executed, which in turn is passed to and processed in the actual Workflow class.

For example, we have the following steps in my Workflow class `A`:

> Step 1 --> Step 2 --> Step 3

`Step 2` is a prerequisite of `Step 3`, while `Step 1` is a requirement of `Step 2`.

So if `A` receives a message called `WaitforStep1` action from the engine, it will mark `Step 1` complete for that particular instance and proceed it to `Step 2`.

Now my issue is: If a message is received that contains the information `WaitforStep2` instead of `WaitforStep1`, the instance will **jump** to `Step 3` directly without passing through `Step 2`.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

*Disclaimer: I'm a beginner at WF.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I employ a Sequence variable that indicates which step a task is currently in. I then put in an `If` statement at the PickBranch Action that verifies whether I'm currently at the correct step or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't skip activities in a workflow without explicitly modeling the workflow to do so. So if messages are received out of order they will be rejected because they are trying to resume an non existent bookmark.

Comment: The weird thing is that it is happening in my case?

Comment: Are you using the Receive activity? If so the runtime queues messages it can't process yet. But activities are never executed out of order if they are arranged in a sequence.

Comment: Sorry, 'total noob at WF. I am using `CodeActivity` if that's what you're referring to?

Comment: A CodeActivity for each step I am hoping. And they are contained in a Sequence? BTW if you are new at WF4 I recommend getting a copy of [Pro WF: Windows Workflow in .NET 4.0](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WF-Windows-Workflow-NET/dp/1430227214/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1309414540&sr=8-1) or attending a [course](http://www.develop.com/training-course/workflow-4.0) (shameless self plug :-) as it takes a bit to get a basic understanding of the principles.

Comment: Oh, you're from Developmentor? Cool! Anyway, yeah they're in a sequence. Structure is: `BaseWorkflow -> Main Workflow Entry -> Main Workflow Body -> Sequence -> Workflow Actions -> (Pickbranch)`. Each step uses a CodeActivity. But there's a base CodeActivity where no specific CodeActivity is created for a step.

Comment: Am I correct in that your three steps are in a Pick? If so that is the problem, a Pick only executes one of its branches. Just put them in a Sequence in the right order.

Comment: Yes, you are right. They are in PickBranch. I think I have the solution to my answer though: I have a sequence variable that describes which step the task is currently at. (I did not code this.) I can check that code if indeed the state of the task is correct. Otherwise, do nothing.